# Undoing auto select radio stations on a 2016 Honda CRV

Tags: honda, audio, crv

I have a 2016 Honda CRV. I had setup my radio station presets on my car. Someone was playing with the controls and "Auto selected" to the strongest radio stations in the area. Is there a way to undo this and make it go back to my old station presets?  It looks like the way they did this was

1. Press the Setup button
2. Scroll to "Auto Select"
3. The radio auto scanned for the strongest signals and overwrote my presets.

There is nothing in the owners manual about this and searching on Google didn't yield any results. The only thing about the "Setup button" was on how to set the time.

Comment: AFAIK you will have to re-program each station to the button of choice individually - which is what you must have done originally. There may have been a separate manual for that specific radio in the car as some cars have different radio (or ICE) options so it is not detailed in the car manual.

Answer (score 1):

As Solar Mike stated in the comments, there's no way to "undo" the Auto Select. You have to go back, one by one, and reset each of your radio stations manually. Radios are not smart enough (yet) to know what you had set in them before. Normally, it is a "fire and forget" kind of thing, where you've setup your channels and they stay put for perpetuity (or until you change the car's battery, whichever comes first).